# np.gradient alternative in c++

Tags: python, c++, numpy, gradient

I need to write a C++ function that caculate the gradient of an array like `np.gradient` function in numpy:

```py
>>> f = np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16], dtype=float)
>>> np.gradient(f)
array([1. , 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5. ])
```

Does any one knows how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implemented a very simple function myself since this question is too easy...

```cpp
vector<double> gradient(vector<double> input){
    if (input.size() <= 1) return input;
    vector<double> res;
    for(int j=0; j<input.size(); j++) {
        int j_left = j - 1;
        int j_right = j + 1;
        if (j_left < 0) {
            j_left = 0; // use your own boundary handler
            j_right = 1;
        }
        if (j_right >= input.size()){
            j_right = input.size() - 1;
            j_left = j_right - 1;
        }
        // gradient value at position j
        double dist_grad = (input[j_right] - input[j_left]) / 2.0;
        res.push_back(dist_grad);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html

```
f'[x] = (f[x+1] - f[x-1]) / 2.0*h + o(h^2)
```

so you can go over the elements from `1` to `n-1` and calculate `(f[i+1] - f[i-1]) / 2.0`

for the edges I believe you have to do:

```
f'[0] = f[1] - f[0]
f'[n] = f[n] = f[n-1]
```